# Deleted copy constructor when member is an unique_ptr

Tags: c++

This code works fine:

```
class Test
{
    int* ptr = new int(10);
};

int main()
{       
     Test o;
     Test t = o;
}
```

But when we use unique_ptr instead raw ptr, we get an error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'Test::Test(const Test&)'
```

And sample code:

```
class Test
{
     std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(1);
};

int main()
{       
     Test o;
     Test t = o;
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: Of course `unique_ptr` doesn't have a copy constructor, only a move constructor. If you want to copy `Test` use a `shared_ptr` (or do a deep copy as the linked answer suggests).

Comment: The hint is in the name.  It wouldn't be a unique pointer if everyone can have one.

Comment: In fact, the original code is _not_ fine. It has a memory leak, and switching to `std::unique_ptr` allows the compiler to prevent this (by not allowing your code).

Answer (score 9):

> What is going on?

You cannot create a second instance of Test because this implies you need a copy of the unique_ptr, which is not possbile. A unique_ptr can only be moved. Try implementing a move asignment operator and move `o` like so:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;

    Test(Test&& other) noexcept
        : ptr(std::move(other.ptr))
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(1);
};

int main()
{
    Test o;
    Test t = std::move(o);
}
```

If you want to copy the int underlying the unique_ptr, you need to define a custom copy constructor like this:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test() = default;

    Test(const Test& other)
        : 
    ptr(new int(*other.ptr))
    {

    }

    Test(Test&& other) noexcept
        : ptr(std::move(other.ptr))
    {
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(1);
};

int main()
{
    Test o;
    Test t = o;
}
```

However, **NOTE**, that the pointers point to two **DIFFERENT** ints.
If you want shared ownership, you have to (and should) use shared_ptr like this:

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_shared<int>(1);
};

int main()
{
    Test o;
    Test t = o;
}
```

Comment: @user463035818 But that isn't a copy of the pointer.  You now have two distinct pointers pointing to two distinct objects which is not the same thing as the OP's first example.

Comment: @user463035818 It's possible that we're talking about different parts of the answer :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it is possible that I had to reload to see the edits... now I am fine with the answer. comments deleted

Comment: I would probably have implemented the copy constructor like this instead: `Test(const Test& other) : Test() { *ptr = *(other.ptr); }` or maybe `Test(int i = 0) : ptr(make_unique<int>(i)) {} Test(const Test& other) : Test(*(other.ptr)) { }`. So that every instance of `Test` gets to use `make_unique` equally and there is a single point of allocation in the class, rather than having default constructed instances use `make_unique` while copied instances use `new`. But that is just me. Either way will "work".

Comment: @RemyLebeau Good point. I probably would not even consider to implement it in this case either way as copying makes limited sense.

Answer (score 6):

> What is going on?

You've swapped from a naked pointer, to one that enforces ownership semantics. One that's smart.

*This is literally the purpose of `unique_ptr`*.

It enforces *unique ownership*.

You can't copy it; only move it.

If you really need `Test` to be copyable, and to be able to share `int`s, you're probably looking for `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. But where can I find a rule like:
Delete copy constructor from class when the class has a unique_ptr member?

Comment: The compiler would have to invoke the copy constructor of the unique_ptr which is deleted. MSVC issues the following error `'Test::Test(const Test &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`.

Comment: @KeyB0rys See: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.copy.ctor#10

Comment: @KeyB0rys As Nathan shows. Logically, how _could_ the class be copied when parts of it are defined as uncopyable? It makes no sense.